# Lexicographically sort a list of sets

Tags: python, sorting

In python - I have a list of sets a la

```
members = [set(1,2,3), set(2,4,1), set(1,3,2), set(2,1,3)]
```

I would like to lexicographically sort these by index, without (if possible) converting to a tuple.

If they were tuples I could simply use:

```
members.sort()
```

Since it is not possible to access a set by index without using something like `iter(members[0]).next()` I have not been able to use `sort(key=)` syntax.  Perhaps I am missing something simple that will make that syntax applicable?

My goal is to avoid the `set` to `tuple` to `set` conversion if possible.

Edit: Given that the order of a set is not fixed I see that this is a moot point.  Most of the answers below deal with a sort of the items in the set.  What about a sort of the sets within the list?  I ask knowing that the sort is just one potential realization as the inter-set order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Sets don't have any order, so even `iter(members[0]).next()` makes no sense as it could return anything.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I would clear up what you mean by return `anything`. That is, there's no guarantee that `iter(set(1,2,3)).next()` will return 1 by the definition of the set, but there is still a good chance that it will return 1 depending on the implementation of set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requests doesn't really make sense, lexicographical sort requires the definition of an order (sort on the first element, if the first is equivalent the compare second element and so on), but `set` elements are not ordered.

You can however define your custom comparison function, but it's really not clear what you're trying to do (there's no "first" element of a set).

Comment: I had not realized that sets were unordered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> members = [set([1,2,3]), set([2,4,1]), set([1,3,2]), set([2,1,3])]
>>> members.sort(key=sorted)
>>> members
0: [set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > members=[{1, 2, 4},{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3},{1, 2}]
> > >       members.sort(key=lambda a:",".join(map(str,sorted(a))))
> > >       members
> > >       [{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}]